# How to catch the mouse&keyboard operation

Tags: c++, qt, events, keyboard, mouse

Using Qt. To catch the event from each key in whole system.

I have known that win API could do this, but how about qt to code. I mean do it without hook and  it can be run in multiple system.

Could do this?Probably Not?

Comment: You can use event filters to catch keyboard or mouse events  but the widget or dialog should have the focus. Does it suffice or you want global shortcuts?

Comment: @Nejat Yes. A global one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global shortcut is not implemented in Qt. But as an alternative you can use [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home). Qxt is an extension library for Qt providing a suite of cross-platform utility classes to add functionality not readily available in Qt. It has Global Shortcut (hot keys) which detects key presses even if the application is minimized or hidden.

After compiling Qxt, link your application to it by adding these to your .pro :

```
CONFIG += qxt
QXT = core gui
```

And include `QxtGlobalShortcut` :

```
#include <QxtGlobalShortcut>
```

Example usage :

```
QxtGlobalShortcut* shortcut = new QxtGlobalShortcut(window);
connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), window, SLOT(toggleVisibility()));
shortcut->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+F"));
```

Now when you press that specific key sequence, the slot would be invoked even if your application is minimized or hidden.

Unfortunately this project is not maintained any more and you may have many difficulties compiling it with Qt 5.*. But you can see the specific parts of the source code and use only the relevant parts in your application.